# Incomplete library definition drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Hello i am getting the following error. What is the problem with this code? I'm trying to add css. Still learning drupal 8. I want to know what is the problem.

Here is the snippet where i add css. My css in the css folder and libraries is at the same level with routing yml file.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal\Core\Asset\Exception\IncompleteLibraryDefinitionException: Incomplete library definition for definition 'test-module' in extension 'test_module' in Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->buildByExtension() (line 96 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryParser.php).

Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->getLibraryDefinitions('test_module')
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->resolveCacheMiss('test_module')
Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheCollector->get('test_module')
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibrariesByExtension('test_module')
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibraryByName('test_module', 'test-module')
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->doGetDependencies(Array)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->getLibrariesWithDependencies(Array)
Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getLibrariesToLoad(Object)
Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getCssAssets(Object, 1)
Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processAssetLibraries(Object, Array)
Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processAttachments(Object)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HtmlResponseSubscriber->onRespond(Object, 'kernel.response', Object)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.response', Object)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->filterResponse(Object, Object, 1)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object)
```

Here is the snippet where i add css. My css in the css folder and libraries is at the same level with routing yml file.

```
        $element = array(
      '#markup' => '<p><b>Saying Hello World in Drupal 8 is cool!</b></p>' . $content,
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' => array(
          'test_module/test-module',
        ),
      ),
    );
```

test_module.libraries.yml

```
test_module_settings:
      path: '/hello/test'
      defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\test_module\Controller\TestModuleController::myCallbackMethod'
        _title: 'Hello World'
      requirements:
        _permission: 'view hello world'
```

Comment: please provide the file where you add your css to module

Comment: @greg606 added the snippet

Comment: and the content of *.libraries.yml file ?

Comment: @greg606 added the libraries.yml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your library is defined in your module/extension, it should have all the following mandatory fields for each library entry:

```
my-library-entry:
  js: {}
  css: {}
  drupalSettings: {}
```

You can replace the curly braces with your `js`, `css` and `drupalSettings` like this:

```
my-library-entry:
  js:
    misc/ajax.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      css/cuddly-slider.css: {}
  drupalSettings:
    myDrupalSetting: null
```

I don't know why the `drupalSettings` entry is required, but that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Content of *.libraries.yml seems incorrect. This is what should go into routing.yml.

libraries.yml should look differently:
https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/cuddly-slider.css: {}
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and the answer was to edit the file carefully and make sure it had spaces and no tabs.